# jQuery plugin to highlight source code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, source-highlighting

Are there any jQuery plugins to highlight the source code shown in an HTML page?
If there are more than one, which one is better to adopt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can highlight the syntax with jQuery and [Chili](http://usejquery.com/blog/highlight-your-source-code-jquery-and-chili). Linked you'll find a nice tutorial to do this.

You can also check the most famous JS highlight plugin: Alex's Gorbatchev [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter).

Answer (score 5):

check this : http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

Answer (score 1):

yes

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Codify

Answer (score 1):

Syntax Highlighter is very useful.

http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

There are too many code lighter plugins on Wordpress plugin page. You can provide it from there